# Best way in Converting DataGrid View to DataSet/DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc, localreport

`DataSet`, `DataTable` and *linq expression* are common `DataSource` values of a `DataGridView`.

Now in reverse, is it possible to pass/bind a `DataGridView` record to `DataSet` or `DataTable`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this Best Answer from [Csharp Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/VIMAL.LAKHERA/LINQResultsetToDatatable06242008042629AM/LINQResultsetToDatatable.aspx):

```
public DataTable LINQToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> varlist)
{
    DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();

    // column names 
    PropertyInfo[] oProps = null;

    if (varlist == null) 
        return dtReturn;

    foreach (T rec in varlist)
    {
        // Use reflection to get property names, to create table, Only first 
        // time, others will follow 
        if (oProps == null)
        {
            oProps = ((Type)rec.GetType()).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
            {
                Type colType = pi.PropertyType;

                if ((colType.IsGenericType) && 
                    (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                {
                    colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
                dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, colType));
            }
        }
        DataRow dr = dtReturn.NewRow();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
        {
            dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(rec, null)==null ? DBNull.Value 
                                                       : pi.GetValue(rec,null);
        }

        dtReturn.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return dtReturn;
}
```

Example: To use this method, just use the following code sample:

```
var vrCountry = from country in objEmpDataContext.CountryMaster
                select new {country.CountryID,country.CountryName};

DataTable dt = LINQToDataTable(vrCountry);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();

Array.ForEach(
    dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToArray(), 
    arg => dataTable.Columns.Add(arg.HeaderText, arg.ValueType));
Array.ForEach(
    dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray(), 
    arg => dataTable.Rows.Add(arg.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(cell => cell.Value)));

return dataTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Public Shared Function DataGridViewToDataTable(ByVal dtg As DataGridView,
    Optional ByVal DataTableName As String = "myDataTable") As DataTable
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable(DataTableName)
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim TotalDatagridviewColumns As Integer = dtg.ColumnCount - 1
        'Add Datacolumn
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In dtg.Columns
            Dim idColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
            idColumn.ColumnName = c.Name
            dt.Columns.Add(idColumn)
        Next
        'Now Iterate thru Datagrid and create the data row
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dtg.Rows
            'Iterate thru datagrid
            row = dt.NewRow 'Create new row
            'Iterate thru Column 1 up to the total number of datagrid columns
            For cn As Integer = 0 To TotalDatagridviewColumns
                row.Item(cn) = dr.Cells(cn).Value
            Next
            'Now add the row to Datarow Collection
            dt.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        'Now return the data table
        Return dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

It was excerpt from this site:
http://www.sourcehints.com/articles/how-to-convert-datagridview-data-to-datatable.html